# list file names with sorted order - ls command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sorting, ls

I have some files in a UNIX directory:

```
/opt/apps/testloc $ ls -mn 
test_1.txt
test_2.txt
test_11.txt
test_12.txt
test_3.txt
```

I want to list this with `ls` command and I need the output in sorted order based on the numbers at the end of the file name. Say output should be like below.

```
test_1.txt, test_2.txt, test_3.txt, test_11.txt, test_12.txt
```

I am not able to get as mentioned. These file names were considered as text and they were sorted as below,

```
test_11.txt, test_12.txt, test_1.txt, test_2.txt, test_3.txt
```

My command `ls –mn` (I need the output to be in comma separated format so I have used `-m`)

I need this to be done to process the files in incremental format in my next process.

Answer (score 2):

If you version of `sort` can do a `version sort` with `-V` then:

```
$ ls | sort -V | awk '{str=str$0", "}END{sub(/, $/,"",str);print str}'
test_1.txt, test_2.txt, test_3.txt, test_11.txt, test_12.txt
```

If not do:

```
$ ls | sort -t_ -nk2,2 | awk '{str=str$0","}END{sub(/,$/,"",str);print str}'
test_1.txt, test_2.txt, test_3.txt, test_11.txt, test_12.txt
```

Comment: add a pipe to `tr '\n' ','` to get a csv-list as OP asked for.

Comment: @Fredrik I don't like `tr '\n' ','` as it replaces the trailing new line with `,` also the OP want `, ` which cannot be done with `tr` so by using `awk` you save a pipe.

Comment: Hi Sudo_O, I have tried the second one with "sort -t" i am not able to get as i require.. the output is same as the previous one. :(

Comment: @Navin are you doing `ls | sort -t_ -nk2,2` on the example case or are the files different from your example? What version of sort do you have, do `sort -v`. See it working here http://ideone.com/scjYTH

Comment: This was a killer for me! Worked like a charm in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

That you require output to be in a specific format tells me that you [shouldn't be using ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Since recursive results aren't required, use a glob.

```
# Bash or ksh + GNU or other sort that handles NUL delimiters

function sortFiles {
    [[ -e $1 ]] || return 1
    typeset a x
    for x; do
        printf '%s %s\0' "${x//[^[:digit:]]}" "$x"
    done |
    LC_ALL=C sort -nz - | {
        while IFS= read -rd '' x; do
            a+=("${x#* }")
        done
        typeset IFS=,
        printf '%s\n' "${a[*]}"
    }
}

sortFiles *
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the file names contain exactly one `_` character, followed by a numeric value, this relatively simple script will sort file names by the numeric field and output them in a `,[space]` separated list (as `ls -m` does):

```
ls -1 *_* | sort -t_ -n -k2 | sed ':0 N;s/\n/, /;t0'
```

However, if there are multiple `_` characters in file names and you want to sort them by the last numeric field (not necessarily the same within the file names, e.g. `test_1_3.txt` and `test_2.txt`), more complex script is required:

```
ls -1 *_* |
awk -F '_' '
{
  key[gensub(/\..*$/, "", 1, $NF) "a" NR] = NR;
  name[NR] = $0;
}
END {
  len = asorti(key, keysorted, "@ind_num_asc");
  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    printf "%s, ", name[key[keysorted[i] ] ];
  }
  printf "%s\n", name[key[keysorted[len] ] ];
}'
```

Answer (score -1):

ls -al | sort +4n : List the files in the
 ascending order of the file-size. i.e
sorted by 5th filed and displaying
smallest files first.